# Read More / Read Less Button - When clicking on Read Less, it loses its position instead of going back to where it was

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Read More/Read Less button on my website to hide long text. My website is on the following link: (http://raywebsolution.com/mcmillan) My problem is that when I click on the Read Less Button to close the expanded area, it doesn't go back to where I was on the website. It loses its position completely. I am adding a code example which I have used.

```js
function readMoreRome() { //finds function
    var dots = document.getElementById("dots"); //returns element that has the ID attribute with value, searches for dots
    var moreText = document.getElementById("more"); // '' '' searches for more
    var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn"); // '' '' searches for myBtn

    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; //button says read more to show more text
        moreText.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; //button says read less to show less text
        moreText.style.display = "inline";
    }
}

function readMoreBuda() { //finds function
    var dots = document.getElementById("dots2"); //returns element that has the ID attribute with value
    var moreText = document.getElementById("more2"); // '' '' searches for more2
    var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn2"); // '' '' searches for myBtn2

    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; //button says read more to show more text
        moreText.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; //button says read less to show less text
        moreText.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <h2>Visit Budapest</h2>
    <div class="info"> <span class="date"><i class="far fa-calendar"></i> November 12, 2019</span> <span class="comment"><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i> 2 comments</span> </div>
    <div class="img"><img src="img/szechenyi.jpg" style="height:200px;"> </div>
    <p><i>Széchenyi Thermal Baths </i></p>
    <p>
        Budapest is the capital city of Hungary. It is best known for its arts and culture. It is a relatively small city, however there are much to see and do.
        <span id="dots2">...</span>
        <span id="more2">Situated on thermal springs, there are many naturally heated baths to relax in, the Széchenyi baths are the largest with 15 indoor baths and 3 outdoor. There are many spectacular viewpoints in Budapest, great for capturing the views of the city. From 360 panoramic views up at St Stephens Basilica to a wide view of the parliament and the River at Fisherman’s Bastion. Visit the Museum of Fine Arts and enjoy a day amongst famous European art. Classical music lovers will appreciate a performance at the Academy of Music.</span>
    </p>
    <button onclick="readMoreBuda()" id="myBtn2">Read more</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="card">
    <h2>Visit Barcelona</h2>
    <div class="info"> <span class="date"><i class="far fa-calendar"></i> December 06, 2019</span> <span class="comment"><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i> 5 comments</span> </div>
    <div class="img"><img src="img/guell-park.jpg" style="height:200px;"></div>
    <p><i>Park Güell </i></p>
    <p>
        Barcelona, framed for its individuality, cultural interest, and physical beauty, home to art and architecture. Facing the Mediterranean to the southeast,
        <span id="dots3">...</span>
        <span id="more3"> the city is one of a kind. Upon visiting make sure you visit the spectacular and unique Park Güell which was firstly designed for a town up in the mountains by artist Antoni Gaudí. Gaudí's work is admired by architects around the World as being one of the most unique and distinctive styles in modern architecture. Other places worth visiting is the La Sagrada Família, is a giant basilica. With beaches on your doorstop, and art and city culture, this diverse city has everything to offer.</span>
    </p>
    <button onclick="readMoreBarca()" id="myBtn3">Read more</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You should consider event delegation and use of `data-*` attributes in buttons instead of defining an own function for every city.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I have change it to something like this:
function readMore(city) {
   let dots = document.querySelector(`[data-city="${city}"] .dots`);
    let moreText = document.querySelector(`[data-city="${city}"] .more`); 
    let btnText = document.querySelector(`[data-city="${city}"] .myBtn`);
 .....................

But  this doesn't solve the main issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), let the machine do the work for you instead of writing a handler function for every card. It would also be more convenient to update the page when you don't have to update the JS part at all, when adding or removing or rearranging the cards. To achieve this, we use `id`less markup, like this:

```js
const allCards = document.querySelectorAll('.all-cards');

function toggleText (e) {
    if (e.target.tagName !== 'BUTTON') {return;} // Quit, not clicked on a button
    const button = e.target,
    card = e.target.parentElement,
    hide = card.querySelector('.three-dots'),
    show = card.querySelector('.expanded-text'),
    state = !+button.getAttribute('data-state'),
    pos = +button.getAttribute('data-pos');

  // Make the changes to the page
  hide.classList.toggle('hidden');
  show.classList.toggle('hidden');
  button.setAttribute('data-state', +state);
  button.textContent = (state) ? 'Read less' : 'Read more';
  
  // Save/adjust scroll position
  // posDelta depends on the space to scroll after the last card.
  // If there is space, toggle the comment on the const lines below
  const posDelta = (button.parentElement === allCards.lastElementChild) ? 0 : -show.offsetHeight;
  // const posDelta = -show.offsetHeight;  
  if (state) {
    e.target.setAttribute('data-pos', posDelta);
  } else {
    window.scrollBy(0, pos);
  }

  return;
}

// Attach an event listener for each `.all-cards` element on the page
allCards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', toggleText));
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.card img {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-cards">
  <div class="card">
      <h2>Visit Budapest</h2>
      <div class="info"> <span class="date"><i class="far fa-calendar"></i> November 12, 2019</span> <span class="comment"><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i> 2 comments</span> </div>
      <div class="img"><img src="img/szechenyi.jpg"> </div>
      <p><i>Széchenyi Thermal Baths </i></p>
      <p>
          Budapest is the capital city of Hungary. It is best known for its arts and culture. It is a relatively small city, however there are much to see and do.
          <span class="three-dots">...</span>
          <span class="expanded-text hidden">Situated on thermal springs, there are many naturally heated baths to relax in, the Széchenyi baths are the largest with 15 indoor baths and 3 outdoor. There are many spectacular viewpoints in Budapest, great for capturing the views of the city. From 360 panoramic views up at St Stephens Basilica to a wide view of the parliament and the River at Fisherman’s Bastion. Visit the Museum of Fine Arts and enjoy a day amongst famous European art. Classical music lovers will appreciate a performance at the Academy of Music.</span>
      </p>
      <button data-state="0">Read more</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="card">
      <h2>Visit Barcelona</h2>
      <div class="info"> <span class="date"><i class="far fa-calendar"></i> December 06, 2019</span> <span class="comment"><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i> 5 comments</span> </div>
      <div class="img"><img src="img/guell-park.jpg"></div>
      <p><i>Park Güell </i></p>
      <p>
          Barcelona, framed for its individuality, cultural interest, and physical beauty, home to art and architecture. Facing the Mediterranean to the southeast,
          <span class="three-dots">...</span>
          <span class="expanded-text hidden"> the city is one of a kind. Upon visiting make sure you visit the spectacular and unique Park Güell which was firstly designed for a town up in the mountains by artist Antoni Gaudí. Gaudí's work is admired by architects around the World as being one of the most unique and distinctive styles in modern architecture. Other places worth visiting is the La Sagrada Família, is a giant basilica. With beaches on your doorstop, and art and city culture, this diverse city has everything to offer.</span>
      </p>
      <button data-state="0">Read more</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice, that all the `id`s and inline events are removed, and class `hidden` is added to the spans to hide at page load. Instead of inline events, we've delegated a single click event to the wrapper element of all the cards using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in JS. In the handler function we can find the clicked button from the event's event object, which is passed to the event handler function automatically by the browser (the argument `e` in the code). Inline styles have been also replaced with a simple class name change, this reduces the code and makes everything much more simple.

The target elements are marked with class attributes in the HTML (`three-dots` and `expand-text`). The code stores the height of the expanded text into `data-pos` attribute of the buttons, and restores the original position when "Read less" button is clicked. `data-state` attribute stores the information for changing the view on the page. The button must be a direct child of the card div, other parts of the markup structure can be changed, as long as the classes for the three-dots-span and the text to expand elements are preserved.

If you always will have more content on the page after the cards, or the page has a fair bottom margin, then you can remove the longer version of `posDelta`, and use the short version only.

Comment: Ok Teemu, it is currently not working on my site. When I click the Read More, nothing happens. Actually, when I click on Buda, only Buda must expand and collapse and same goes for barcelona.

Comment: @SewumberRay As you can see, the code works in the snippet. I've fixed the issue with multiple opened texts. If you can't get the code to work on your page, and there's any difference in the markup structure of the card, please edit your question so, that the structure is exactly the same as it is on your page. Also, did you notice the new `div` element wrapping all the cards? It's also very rare, that "_nothing happens_", have you taken a look at the console for errors?

Comment: I apologies, I am new to this platform and didn't know how to add code to question. I copied a similar code. My correct question and the right code is on this link. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66043122/issue-with-the-readmore-and-less-button-when-readless-button-is-clicked-the-e) @Teemu  please help me.

Comment: Uhh ... I'd suggest you to change the structure similar to what you have in this question. It's magnitudes more clear. I'll make a small adjust to my code, so that you can mark the elements to hide and show with classes, that way the structure itself is not that important. Additional to all that, hardcoded inline styles are not a good practice, please learn how to use [CSS Stylesheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) (you will need a stylesheet to get the code in this answer to work too).

Comment: @SewumberRay I've updated my code now. It doesn't fit to your HTML in your previous question linked in the comment above, but now you can add the classes in the correct elements in your real markup. Only the button must be a direct child of the card element.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Teemu, very much appreciated. However, I haven't hardcode inline styles in the one that I have used on my website. Also I have nothing like Cards etc. If possible do have a look at the correct one that I have posted  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66043122/issue-with-the-readmore-and-less-button-when-readless-button-is-clicked-the-e) I will be very grateful.

Comment: I've no more time for this for now, you should be able to fit the code with your markup quite easily, just read everything what is said in the answer. You can also play with a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7drpkaxu/1/), that might be helpful when you make the fitting. "Card" is the div element wrapping all the information of a single city, you've used that as a class in the example on this post. There's a small jump in the Stack Snippet when clicking Read less button, that doesn't occur at jsFiddle, it's probably due to the different CSS normalizer used for the pages, probably the box-model.

Comment: One last last thing, please. I got everything to be working fine on jsFiddle but not on my website. Please note I am using joomla as CMS and I have a template but adding this code as a RAW HTML. (I do this since a long time n understand the concept). I guess the problem could be a conflict. Is there any way you can replace some words that could be conflicting with other codes in your script? Such as "Button" which is widely used in many codes? Thanks.

Comment: All the variables in the function are local to the function, they do no interfere with other variables.

Comment: I have done everything as you said but my bad luck.. I get the ReadMore button but when I click on it, nothing happens. (www.raywebsolution.com/mcmillan) - About us section . But it work well on jFiddle. I feel like crying. Anyway, many thanks for your help. This solution may be useful for somebody else.

Comment: It will be useful for you too = ). Have you seen any error messages in the console?

Comment: I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at (index):671". But when I click on (index):671, there is nothing.

Comment: You're missing the wrapper element. I made [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/ewkn6jty/1/) with your original HTML. Notice, that you must add the wrapper with class `all-cards`, otherwise the code doesn't work at all. There was some invalid HTML also, I've fixed the bugging parts (div can't be a child of a span or p elements, an orphan closing span tag).

Comment: I really appreciate you are doing a lot to help me. I don't have words to thank you. I have pasted the code exactly as your jFiddle on the website. I still can't get the button to work. I have removed my existing Jscript and replaced with yours

Comment: Mine was:
function readMore(city) {
   let dots = document.querySelector(`[data-city="${city}"] .dots`);
    let moreText = document.querySelector(`[data-city="${city}"] .more`); 
    let btnText = document.querySelector(`[data-city="${city}"] .myBtn`);

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.textContent = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}

Comment: If the error is still the same, and the wrapper exists, make sure you run this code after the wrapper is inserted into the DOM. On the live page the button is also in the hidden section, it's not visible, hence you can't even click the buttons. I've moved the button to the `.card` div, the changes to your HTML are commented in the first card in that fiddle. If you can follow the comments exactly, and replicate the changes in your template, there shouldn't be anything preventing the code to run and work as intended.

Comment: I took liberty to peek your code on the live site. Just put all the JS provided by my answer to a `$(function () {...});` or into a DOMContentLoaded handler or at the bottom of the body. Currently the script is run in the head section, and `.all-cards` doesn't exist at the time the script is run, because even the body element doesn't exist yet.

Comment: You are a genius, a superhero bro. Thank you so much. You really did all your best to help me.. I am really really very thankful. I got it to work and fully understand it also. I put the Jscript in the bottom of the body and everything was fixed. Now when using the ReadMore/Less button in another section of the website, I just replaced all-cards with all-cards1 in the HTML & Jscript. It replicate the code but this in not an issue for me. Thanks again.

Comment: @SewumberRay Umm ... no, you should not double the code, like I said earlier, let the machine do the work. I've updated the code so, that it's all you need, it now attaches the event to every element having class `all-cards` automatically. This will work nevertheless there are one or more of those elements, and even if there's not any of them.

Comment: Thats great @Teemu. Thanks again. You are the best.

Comment: new issue, the code is not compatible on Safari Browser. It works but does not keep position. Is there any fix for this? Anything to add in the Javascript?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have Safari for testing. It's probably something in the measurements of the elements. You could try to log `posDelta` after it's been calculated, then compare the results in Safari and other browsers.